# How to hide Graphql Apis from everyone on internet

Tags: django, graphql

I have a website built using Python Django framework and backend APIs are designed using GraphQL api.

The graphql url is like below,

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/graphql/
```

All my apis are currently accessible by everyone on the internet. I need to hide those behind some authentication (login / password).

Please suggest some ways to fix this.

I am already using below for user authentication,
https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

However, the url is still accessible to everyone. I need it behind username password.

Comment: Have you tried a google search for "django user authentication" ?

Comment: You could have a look at https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/

Comment: @JohnGordon I am already using the one found here, https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/